# How to set design-time property default values?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

According to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autosize.aspx), there's a note about `Label`'s `AutoSize` property:

> When added to a form using the designer, the default value is true. When instantiated from code, the default value is false.

The question is: how can I override a `Label` control and set its `AutoSize` property's **design-time** default value to `false`?

(Update)

And this doesn't work:

```
class MyLabel : Label
{
    const bool defaultAutoSize = false;

    public MyLabel()
    {
        AutoSize = defaultAutoSize;
    }

    [DefaultValue(defaultAutoSize)]
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return base.AutoSize;
        }
        set
        {
            base.AutoSize = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Label` control has an attribute:

```
[ToolboxItem("System.Windows.Forms.Design.AutoSizeToolboxItem,System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
```

which cause the strange `AutoSize` problem.

I can disable it by this:

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
class MyLabel : Label
{
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Simply use inheritance. You will have to use your custom Label instead of the System one, though.

```
public class MyLabel:Label
{
    public MyLabel():base()
    {
        base.AutoSize = false;
    }
}
```

You can put this directly into your code and modify the code like below. Or you can put this class into its own library, which you should then be able to load into the toolbox and use like any other component.

For this to work from the toolbox, it seems that you need to override the InitLayout, like below, and add an attribute to the AutoSize property so it is not serialized into the designer:

```
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return base.AutoSize;
        }
        set
        {
            base.AutoSize = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void InitLayout()
    {
        base.InitLayout();
        base.AutoSize = false;
    }
```

If you are not using the toolbox, then once you drop your normal label onto your form, you need to go into the `[Form].Designer.cs` and find and modify your labels:

```
this.label1 = new MyLabel();// new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

//this.label1.AutoSize = true;
```

You have to remove the preset AutoSize property because when you drop the label it sets it in the designer, and even if you change the label instantiation to be your type, the manual AutoSize set will override your default

Comment: I just did. I will update my code to show how this has to be implemented.

Comment: Ummm, is that a typo in your comment, because the normal default is true. So, defaulting to false is what you asked for....

Comment: That's why I want to set the **default** value. I dont' want to modify the code every time I create a new control. And yes, defaulting to false is what I asked for.

Comment: Sorry, I had not actually done the toolbox part as my memory was that it just worked, however I updated the code with what I did to resolve this so that it does not generate the autosize, and will use the default. Let me know if this works for you now. :)

Comment: It does work only when I remove `override` before the bool `AutoSize`

Answer (score 3):

See the [`DefaultValueAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx)

Like so:

```
public class MyLabel : Label
{
    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(false)]
    public override bool AutoSize
    {
        get
        {
            return base.AutoSize;
        }
        set
        {
            base.AutoSize = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  This does not work as expected.  <s>Tung's answer is correct.</s> ...Wrong again.

Comment: @EFanZh Sure it does...what problem are you encountering?

Comment: If you drag the control from the toolbox, the Windows Form Designer auto generate `AutoSize = true` code.

Comment: @EFanZh My mistake, you're right. Tung's answer is the correct one.  You must use `new` instead of `override` and not access the `base.AutoSize` property.